# Make custom filtering, combining two fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a django rest framework model with the following definition

```
class Test(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

I want a to generate a custom lookup method that will receive id OR username and return the same results. for example if i call the api like api/Test/?custom_lookup_method=12345 OR api/Test/?custom_lookup_method=john_smith to return the same filter results. Is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ModelViewset, you can customize get_queryset

```
class TestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    serializer_class = YourSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        value = self.kwargs['query']
        queryset = Test.objects.filter(Q(id__contains=value) |
                                Q(username__icontains=value))
        return queryset
#urls.py
router.register(r'test/(?P<query>[0-9A-Za-z]+)', TestViewSet)
```

now run test/?query=12345 or test/?query=john

Comment: It nevers get into the method filter_query

Comment: sorry, now it gets into method

Comment: still not gets into

Comment: please use api/Test/?lookup=12345 or api/Test/?lookup=john_smith

Comment: i am using it exactly as you said

Comment: Just to notice that i am using viewsets.ModelViewSet and not APIView, do ModelViewSet handle the filters differently ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224973/discussion-between-krishna-singhal-and-pikk).